# How can I run a terminal command from within any app and output the result (on Mac)?

Tags: command-line, keybindings, shortcuts-app, macos

No matter what app I am in, I would like to do a keyboard shortcut which allows me to enter a terminal command and run it, and the output will be written to wherever my cursor is, if it is in a text field.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `pbcopy`?  Run your Terminal command and pipe the output to your clipboard:  `ls -la | pbcopy`.  But, you can't run Terminal from *within* any app.  If the  app doesn't support it, you can't do it.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @allan A shortcut might work, actually.

Comment: I'll up vote that answer @nohillside because it fits what the OP's asking for.  I just think there is more to what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shortcuts.app to create a shortcut like

[image]

and assign it to a key combination.